# Unknown fix for error: cl--generic-build-combined-method: Cyclic definition: %S: loadhist-unload-element

Tags: magit, transient-library, transients, magit-status

I'm using emacs 27.2 and magit version 20231109.935. When I'm inside a directory and try to run `magit-status` or `magit-init` I get the error message in the title:
`cl--generic-build-combined-method: Cyclic definition: %S: loadhist-unload-element`. What is causing this error and how do I resolve it?

I get the following debug message when I put `debug-on-entry` on `loadhist-unload-element`:

```
Debugger entered--entering a function:
* loadhist-unload-element((defun . seq-doseq))
  mapc(loadhist-unload-element ((defun . seq-doseq) (defun . seq--pcase-macroexpander) (define-symbol-props (pcase-macroexpander seq) (edebug-form-spec seq--pcase-macroexpander)) (defun . seq-let) (defun . seq-elt) (cl-defmethod seq-elt nil t t) (defun . \(setf\ seq-elt\)) (cl-defmethod \(setf\ seq-elt\) nil t array t) (cl-defmethod \(setf\ seq-elt\) nil t cons t) (defun . seq-length) (cl-defmethod seq-length nil t) (defun . seq-first) (defun . seq-rest) (defun . seq-do) (cl-defmethod seq-do nil t t) (defun . seq-each) (defun . seq-do-indexed) (defun . seqp) (cl-defmethod seqp nil t) (defun . seq-copy) (cl-defmethod seq-copy nil t) (defun . seq-subseq) (cl-defmethod seq-subseq nil t t) (defun . seq-map) (cl-defmethod seq-map nil t t) (defun . seq-map-indexed) (cl-defmethod seq-map nil t sequence) (defun . seq-mapn) (cl-defmethod seq-mapn nil t t) (defun . seq-drop) (cl-defmethod seq-drop nil t t) (t . seq-take) (defun . seq-take) (cl-defmethod seq-take nil t t) (defun . seq-drop-while) (cl-defmethod seq-drop-while nil t t) (defun . seq-take-while) (cl-defmethod seq-take-while nil t t) (defun . seq-empty-p) (cl-defmethod seq-empty-p nil t) (defun . seq-sort) (cl-defmethod seq-sort nil t t) (cl-defmethod seq-sort nil t list) (t . seq-sort-by) (defun . seq-sort-by) (defun . seq-reverse) (cl-defmethod seq-reverse nil t) (cl-defmethod seq-reverse nil sequence) (t . seq-concatenate) (defun . seq-concatenate) ...))
  unload-feature(seq force)
  byte-code("\300\301!\210\300\302!\210\300\303!\210\300\304!\210\300\305!\210\306\307!\203%\0\310\311!\204%\0\312\307\313\"\210\300\307!\210\300\314!\210\300\315!\210\316..." [require cl-lib compat dash eieio subr-x featurep seq fboundp seq-keep unload-feature force crm magit-section custom-declare-variable magit-completing-read-function funcall function #f(compiled-function () #<bytecode 0x1ff80f05b339>) "Function to be called when requesting input from t..." :group magit-essentials :type (radio (function-item magit-builtin-completing-read) (function-item magit-ido-completing-read) (function-item ivy-completing-read) (function-item helm--completing-read-default) (function :tag "Other function")) magit-dwim-selection #f(compiled-function () #<bytecode 0x1ff80f05b345>) "When not to offer alternatives and ask for confirm..." :package-version (magit . "2.12.0") magit-commands (repeat (list (symbol :tag "Command") (choice (const :tag "for all prompts" nil) (regexp :tag "for prompts matching regexp")) (choice (const :tag "offer other choices" nil) (const :tag "require confirmation" ask) (const :tag "use default without confirmation" t))))] 10)
  require(magit-base)
  byte-code("\301\302!\210\301\303!\210\301\304!\210\301\305!\210\301\306!\210\301\307!\210\301\310!\210\10\204=\0\311 \203=\0\31210\0\301\313!0\202<\0\314\20..." [magit-inhibit-libgit require magit-base magit-git magit-mode magit-margin magit-process magit-transient magit-autorevert magit--libgit-available-p (error) magit-libgit error message "Error while loading `magit-libgit': %S" "That is not fatal.  The `libegit2' module just won..." custom-declare-group magit nil "Controlling Git from Emacs." :link (url-link "https://magit.vc") (info-link "(magit)FAQ") (info-link "(magit)") :group tools magit-essentials "Options that every Magit user should briefly think..." (info-link "(magit)Essential Settings") magit-miscellaneous "Miscellaneous Magit options." magit-commands "Options controlling behavior of certain commands." magit-modes "Modes used or provided by Magit." magit-buffers "Options concerning Magit buffers." (info-link "(magit)Modes and Buffers") magit-refresh "Options controlling how Magit buffers are refreshe..." (info-link "(magit)Automatic Refreshing of Magit Buffers") magit-faces "Faces used by Magit." faces custom-add-to-group diff-refine-added custom-face diff-refine-removed magit-extensions "Extensions to Magit." ...] 18)
  require(magit-core)
  eval-buffer(#<buffer  *load*-461736> nil "/Users/aberk/.emacs.d/elpa/magit-20231109.935/magi..." nil t)  ; Reading at buffer position 2446
  load-with-code-conversion("/Users/aberk/.emacs.d/elpa/magit-20231109.935/magi..." "/Users/aberk/.emacs.d/elpa/magit-20231109.935/magi..." nil t)
  require(magit)
  eval-buffer(#<buffer  *load*> nil "/Users/aberk/.emacs.d/elpa/magit-20231109.935/magi..." nil t)  ; Reading at buffer position 992
  load-with-code-conversion("/Users/aberk/.emacs.d/elpa/magit-20231109.935/magi..." "/Users/aberk/.emacs.d/elpa/magit-20231109.935/magi..." nil t)
  autoload-do-load((autoload "magit-status" "Show the status of the current Git repository in a..." t nil) magit-status)
  command-execute(magit-status)
```

**Update:** I think this error is caused by transient.el, a dependency of `magit`. Trying to update `magit` gave me the error

```
Compiling file ~/.emacs.d/elpa/transient-20231112.923/transient.el at Thu Nov 16 19:18:53 2023
Entering directory ‘~/.emacs.d/elpa/transient-20231112.923/’
transient.el:61:1:Error: Cyclic definition: %S: loadhist-unload-element
```

This error still has not been resolved.
Could it be a backward compatibility issue with Emacs 27.2? Could it be something wrong with transient?

Comment: https://emacs.stackexchange.com/tags/elisp/info

Comment: I have fixed the issue by downgrading transient to version 0.4.3.